# Flowing Problem gltf 3D Model over MapBox Map

Tags: 3d, mapbox-gl-js, gltf

I have a project similar, adding gltf 3D Model on map using mapbox gl with three.js from the [example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-3d-model/).

When i load gltf model of example (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/34M_17/34M_17.gltf) , everything  is fine,
but after load my gltf model and change view of camera dirction with right click, i have realized that my model floating over the map.

Where was i fail? Did i need new transformation parameters, if i how can calculate them.
if Someone can help i will be very pleasure.

I changed three thing;

- center of map and model to [28.963774, 41.0163]
- scale value multiply 200 times otherwise model seems so small
- i use my gltf model code is here
  https://github.com/akinba/gltf/blob/master/NewFeatureType.gltf

Answer (score 0):

Found that, real problem is gltf file itself. I have convert gltf from obj format by using FME. FME is good for multiple jobs but need fine adjustments.

With [Blender](https://www.blender.org/), we put center of object to XY axis and Z axis=0, than [export](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO) to gltf format.

Now result is same as [example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/34M_17/34M_17.gltf)